# Skip first byte of NSData

Tags: swift

How skip first byte of NSData ? The first byte is the date length, so I want to skip it.

```
let bleData = NSData(data: characteristic.value)
```

Declaration:

```
var value: Data? { get }
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Have you tried `dropFirst(1)` or `remove(at: 0)`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `dropFirst()` or mutating method `popFirst()` which doesn't require the data not to be empty

Comment: don't convert your data to `NSData`  `if let bleData = characteristic.value?.dropFirst() {`